# Can I populate a custom dimension in google analytics from page metadata?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to report on website performance for a website with editors in various UK regions (Eg. South-West, North, North-East) that don't map to regions that GA understands.

Is it possible to embed the region into the metadata of the page and then read that via Google Analytics as a hit for a custom dimension? If so how do I format the metadata tag on the page?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do this. On your page, below wherever it is that you have the Google Tag Manager script, you'll want to push your values into the data layer. I recommend something along the lines of the following:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  window.dataLayer.push({
    'uk-region': 'South-West' //As applicable
  });
</script>
```

And then you'll need a couple of things in GTM in order to pick this up. First, create a new Data Layer Variable and populate the "Data Layer Variable Name" with the "uk-region" name I used above, or whatever else you want to identify it with. Give it a useful name like "uk-region" at the top.
[image: GTM Variable]

In your Google Analytics page view tag then, you'll need to set up the custom dimension mapping. Click the box for "Enable overriding settings in this tag" and a dropdown will appear with "More Settings". Expand the "Custom Dimensions" and click the "+ Add Custom Dimension" button. Specify the number custom dimension you wish to populate under Index and in the value, we'll specify the variable we created with `{{uk-region}}`.

[image: Google Analytics Configuration]

Test your container to ensure it's getting picked up as it should, then publish to commit the container to your website.